# Expected performance of training tf.keras.Sequential model with model.fit, model.fit_generator and model.train_on_batch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow to train a 1D CNN to detect specific events from sensor data. While the data with tens of millions samples easily fits to the ram in the form of an 1D float array, it obviously takes a huge amount of memory to store the data as a N x inputDim array that can be passed to model.fit for training. While I can use model.fit_generator or model.train_on_batch to generate the required mini batches on the fly, for some reason I am observing a huge performance gap between model.fit and model.fit_generator & model.train_on_batch even though everything is stored in memory and mini batch generation is fast as it basically only consists of reshaping the data. Therefore, I'm wondering whether I am doing something terribly wrong or if this kind of performance gap is to be expected. I am using the cpu version of Tensorflow 2.0 with 3.2 GHz Intel Core i7 processor (4 cores with multithreading support) and Python 3.6.3. on Mac Os X Mojave.

In short, I created a dummy python script to recreate the issue, and it reveals that with batch size of 64, if takes 407 seconds to run 10 epochs with model.fit, 1852 seconds with model.fit_generator, and 1985 seconds with model.train_on_batch. CPU loads are ~220%, ~130%, and ~120% respectively, and it seems especially odd that model.fit_generator & model.train_on_batch are practically on par, while model.fit_generator should be able to parallelise mini batch creation and model.train_on_batch definitely does not. That is, model.fit (with huge memory requirements) beats the other solution candidates with easily manageable memory requirements by a factor of four. Obviously, CPU loads increase and total training times decrease by increasing batch size, but model.fit is always fastest with a a margin of at least two up to batch size of 8096.

Is this kind of behaviour normal (when there is no GPU involved) or what could be done in order to increase the computation speed of the less memory intensive options? It seems that no such option is available to divide all data into manageable pieces, and then run model.fit in iterative manner.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from tqdm       import tqdm

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import time
import sys
import argparse


class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, inputData, outputData, batchIndices, batchSize, shuffle):
        'Initialization'
        self.inputData    = inputData
        self.outputData   = outputData
        self.batchIndices = batchIndices
        self.batchSize    = batchSize
        self.shuffle      = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int( np.floor( self.inputData.size / self.batchSize ) )

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(self.indexes[index*self.batchSize:(index+1)*self.batchSize])

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(self.inputData.size)
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, INDX):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'

        # Generate data
        X = np.expand_dims( self.inputData[ np.mod( self.batchIndices + np.reshape(INDX,(INDX.size,1)) , inputData.size ) ], axis=2)
        y = self.outputData[INDX,:] 

        return X, y

FLAGS = None

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()


parser.add_argument('--batchSize', type=int,
                default=128,
                help='Batch size')
parser.add_argument('--epochCount', type=int,
                default=5,
                help='Epoch count')

FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()

batchSize = FLAGS.batchSize
epochCount = FLAGS.epochCount

# Data generation

print(' ')
print('Generating data...')

np.random.seed(0) # For reproducible results

inputDim  = int(104)                      # Input  dimension
outputDim = int(  2)                      # Output dimension
N         = int(1049344)                  # Total number of samples
M         = int(5e4)                      # Number of anomalies
trainINDX = np.arange(N, dtype=np.uint32)

inputData = np.sin(trainINDX) + np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.20, size=N) # Source data stored in a single array

anomalyLocations = np.random.choice(N, M, replace=False)

inputData[anomalyLocations] += 0.5

outputData = np.zeros((N,outputDim)) # One-hot encoded target array without ones

for i in range(N):
    if( np.any( np.logical_and( anomalyLocations >= i, anomalyLocations < np.mod(i+inputDim,N) ) ) ): 
        outputData[i,1] = 1 # set class #2 to one if there is at least a single anomaly within range [i,i+inputDim)
    else:
        outputData[i,0] = 1 # set class #1 to one if there are no anomalies within range [i,i+inputDim)

print('...completed')
print(' ')

# Create a model for anomaly detection

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=9, strides=1, padding='valid', dilation_rate=1, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', input_shape=(inputDim,1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=None, padding='valid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu', use_bias=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(outputDim, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile( tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
               loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

print(' ')

relativeIndices = np.arange(inputDim)                       # Indices belonging to a single sample relative to current position
batchIndices    = np.tile( relativeIndices, (batchSize,1) ) # Relative indices tiled into an array of size ( batchSize , inputDim )  
stepsPerEpoch   = int( np.floor( N / batchSize ) )          # Steps per epoch

# Create an intance of dataGenerator class
generator = DataGenerator(inputData, outputData, batchIndices, batchSize=batchSize, shuffle=True)

# Solve by gathering data into a large float32 array of size ( N , inputDim ) and feeding it to model.fit

startTime = time.time()

X = np.expand_dims( inputData[ np.mod( np.tile(relativeIndices,(N,1)) + np.reshape(trainINDX,(N,1)) , N ) ], axis=2)
y = outputData[trainINDX, :]

history = model.fit(x=X, y=y, sample_weight=None, batch_size=batchSize, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=None, shuffle=True, epochs=epochCount)

referenceTime = time.time() - startTime
print(' ')
print('Total solution time with model.fit: %6.3f seconds' % referenceTime)

# Solve with model.fit_generator  

startTime = time.time()

history = model.fit_generator(generator=generator, steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch, verbose=1, callbacks=None, epochs=epochCount, max_queue_size=1024, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=4)

generatorTime = time.time() - startTime
print(' ')
print('Total solution time with model.fit_generator: %6.3f seconds (%6.2f %% more)' % (generatorTime, 100.0 * generatorTime/referenceTime))
print(' ')

# Solve by gathering data into batches of size ( batchSize , inputDim ) and feeding it to model.train_on_batch

startTime = time.time()

for epoch in range(epochCount):

    print(' ')
    print('Training epoch # %2d ...' % (epoch+1))
    print(' ')

    np.random.shuffle(trainINDX)

    epochStartTime = time.time()

    for step in tqdm( range( stepsPerEpoch ) ):

        INDX = trainINDX[ step*batchSize : (step+1)*batchSize ]

        X = np.expand_dims( inputData[ np.mod( batchIndices + np.reshape(INDX,(batchSize,1)) , N ) ], axis=2)
        y = outputData[INDX,:]

        history = model.train_on_batch(x=X, y=y, sample_weight=None, class_weight=None, reset_metrics=False)

    print(' ')
    print('...completed with loss = %9.6e, accuracy = %6.2f %%, %6.2f ms/step' % (history[0], 100.0*history[1], (1000*(time.time() - epochStartTime)/np.floor(trainINDX.size / batchSize))))
    print(' ')

batchTime = time.time() - startTime
print(' ')
print('Total solution time with model.train_on_batch: %6.3f seconds (%6.2f %% more)' % (batchTime, 100.0 * batchTime/referenceTime))
print(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

**model.fit** - suitable if you load the data as numpy-array and train without augmentation.

**model.fit_generator** - if your dataset is too big to fit in the memory or\and you want to apply augmentation on the fly.

**model.train_on_batch** - less common, usually used when training more than one model at a time (GAN for example)

Comment: I am sorry, but in what sense does this answer my question? Obviously, I would simply use model.fit if I had enough memory. Now I am successfully exploiting model.fit_generator with a lot of frustration caused by poor performance. Technically, the operating system extends the memory space by swapping, so reserving e.g. 48 GB of memory in a machine with 32 GB of ram does not always cause a crash, but still leads at least to overall instability of the operating system, total freezing of the computer, and by far the worst performance.